# How to change my HUD?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have seen some videos of people with HUDs that look a ton better then the default, so my question is how do I change my HUD in TF2? Is it something I have to do manually or is there some place where I can download a premade one?

Here its an example video where someone is using a different HUD:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also do it manually, but it requires some skill and time to reach a good result. My suggestion is to search and download HUDs already available.

[GameBanana](http://www.gamebanana.com/guis/cats/434) is one of the best sources and has a good numbers of HUD to browse.

In the specific video you posted the player is using PVHUD, one of the most famous HUDs available. You can download it [here](http://www.ozfortress.com/showthread.php?t=42719).

Another famous one is FrankenHUD, downloadable [here](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/frankenhud).